# Using Indextank for a site search

Tags: php, search, indexing, web-crawler, indextank

Im looking for free easy-to-implement & ad-free alternatives to Google CSE.

I found indextank, which looks like an easy enough way to index content but it doesn't crawl your site. I guess I envisaged being able to pass it an url ala Google CSE.

Therefore, is there an easy way I could setup a PHP script to do the crawling part? i.e. pass it an URL and have it index all webpages on that domain.

End result being I can put a site search on my website.

Comment: If you can index without crawling, there are advantages: you don't have to worry about boilerplate (headers/footers) polluting your document bodies.  Also, it's inevitably faster.  e.g., if you can simply `SELECT * FROM blog_post` and pump the relevant data into indextank, it'll be faster (easier on your server, easier to keep index up to date) and again, no dilution of content with boilerplate.

Comment: Yep I can understand that but a fair amount of the site is static HTML.

Comment: Here's a bash script a dude hacked together for pumping wget output into solr.  This won't be plug-and-play for you, but it may be a good place to start: https://gist.github.com/774946

Comment: @FrankFarmer : If that script was posted in response to an S.O. question, can you please post a link to the question as well. ELSE any context info you can add would be interesting. Thanks

Comment: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2093077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this functionality in my site. Basically I have an HTML form where the user can query:

```
<form method="post" action="[_LINK_HELP_SEARCH_]">
  <div class="static-text">(_INTRO_)</div>
  <input class="inline" name="q" id="search" type="text" value="[_QUERY_]" />
  <input class="inline" type="submit" value="(_SEARCH_)" />
  <div class="micro-text">(_EXAMPLE_)</div>
</form>
```

Note: All [XXX] and (YYY) are template fields, you should substitute in your code.

When the form is sent, a PHP file split the query in words:

```
$query = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $query);
$words = explode(' ', $query);
```

Search for every file in the target folder (

```
$help_files = _get_all_files('help');
$help_files = array_slice($help_files, 0, MAX_RESULTS);
foreach($help_files as $file) {
```

Note that I search only on the 'help' folder, you should adapt this to your own needs. Note also that _get_all_files is a custom function that just lists all PHP files on the given folder.

Then load and parse text:

```
$text_file = '';
$filename = $file['page'];
if (_file_exists($filename)) {
    $text_file = _read_php_file($filename);
}

$text_file = strtolower($text_file);
$text_file = strip_tags($text_file);
$text_file = preg_replace('/\[_(.*?)_\]/', '...', $text_file);
$text_file = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '[\t\n]'), ' ', $text_file);
```

Note here that _read_php_file reads the PHP content file, i.e. just the same that a user will get if he calls this file. This is because I use templates and my HTML files are not direct. If you use static HTML, you can use *readfile()* or similar.

Next, search words:

```
$score = 0;
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($text_file, $word) !== false) {
        $score++;
    }
}
```

I know it could be optimized, but that wasn't necessary for the moment. Basically, this piece of code counts each word found in the text and gets an *score*.

Next you may be interested in creating a text excerpt:

```
$pos = strpos($text_file, $words[0]);
$cut_ini = max($pos - RESUME_LIMIT/2, 0);
$extract = substr($text_file, $cut_ini, RESUME_LIMIT);
$extract = "...$extract...";
```

And last, I store all this info in the output array (for each file found), if score is significative:

```
if (($score > 0) && (count($words) / $score > 0.7)) {
    $result = array (
        'extract'   => $extract,
        'title'     => $file['title'],
        'link'      => $file['page'],
        'score'     => $score
    );
    $results[] = $result;
}
```

Of course all this must be reapeated for each file you want to index and at the end, you must sort your array:

```
usort($results, "_search_sort");
```

With this function:

```
function _search_sort($a, $b) {
    if ($a['score'] == $b['score']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['score'] > $b['score']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

At the end you will have a sorted array with your searching results. I hope this helps.